# How to scrape the Event details using python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the complete date details as: `SATURDAY, JANUARY 30, 2021 AT 8:30 PM UTC+05:30 – 12:30 AM UTC+05:30`

Code tag:

```
<div class="j83agx80 cbu4d94t obtkqiv7 sv5sfqaa">
    <div class="bi6gxh9e aov4n071">
        <h2 class="gmql0nx0 l94mrbxd p1ri9a11 lzcic4wl d2edcug0 hpfvmrgz" dir="auto">
            <span class="d2edcug0 hpfvmrgz qv66sw1b c1et5uql rrkovp55 a8c37x1j keod5gw0 nxhoafnm aigsh9s9 d3f4x2em fe6kdd0r mau55g9w c8b282yb iv3no6db jq4qci2q a3bd9o3v hnhda86s jdix4yx3 hzawbc8m" dir="auto">
                ::before
                "SATURDAY, JANUARY 30, 2021 AT 8:30 PM UTC+05:30 – 12:30 AM UTC+05:30"
                ::after
            </span>
        </h2>
    </div>
```

Can anyone help me out with this...
I tried with the below code but not working:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request as url
import requests

source = url.urlopen('https://www.facebook.com/events/777016493046448/')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

result = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'d2edcug0 hpfvmrgz qv66sw1b c1et5uql rrkovp55 a8c37x1j keod5gw0 nxhoafnm aigsh9s9 d3f4x2em fe6kdd0r mau55g9w c8b282yb iv3no6db jq4qci2q a3bd9o3v hnhda86s jdix4yx3 hzawbc8m'}).text

print(result)
```

Comment: Why would you use `selenium-webdriver` tag if you're not actually using it?

Comment: It appears differently to me. I see it under `#event_time_info div[content]`

Comment: The ```html``` structure is not the same structure of the ```url``` you've provided!

Comment: @Ruvee, please consider the url itself

Comment: Ok! Which part of the page you're interested in? There are several dates on the page!

Comment: Entire part: "SATURDAY, JANUARY 30, 2021 AT 8:30 PM UTC+05:30 – 12:30 AM UTC+05:30"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/events/777016493046448/')
html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find('div', class_=['2ycp', '_5xhk'])
print(result.text)
driver.close()
```

You also need to install chromedriver and it to path.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working perfectly fine.